# Measure message transmission speed

Tags: java, time

I am making a network application and I would like to display the time messages take to travel from sender to receiver.

What ways you believe are fit to implement this feature ?

What I have thought is storing the current time on message and comparing with time on receiver end. Although on java doc it says the current Time given might be different depending on OS.

> How should I get the current Time so that it will be same on every OS?
>   (or just OSX and win)

p.s: The application in most cases is about just sending messages and not expecting something back.

Comment: keep in mind that time could be different between the sender and the receiver because of potential differences in clocking speeds and other issues. storing the time within the message may not aways yield the expected results. how accurate do you need to be?

Comment: Its more for demonstration rather than really accurate numbers. Telling a difference between 1sec and 1.3 sec is enough

Comment: if you are interested in measuring network latency, the simplest thing that you could do is measure the roundtrip of a simple package such as *ping*. your approach could work but you have to make sure that the clocks of the two hosts are synchronized in order to avoid large variances. Without proper synchronization it may happen that the receiver sees a timestamp grater than the current local time. As an example take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristian%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to make use of an NTP (Network Time Protocol) server to sync the time on both machines. You can also query a NTP server from your applications and get the correct time which can then be used for your calculation.

Comment: @Giannis please share the solution which was finalized by you. If you are interested in NTP time synchronization, a sample implementation of an NTP client is available at: http://commons.apache.org/net/

Comment: My clients connect to an RMI server.Could I use the time of that RMI server for this purpose? Although I don't want to query the server each time a message is received /sent since that can be quite rapid.

Comment: @Giannis, I am not sure as to whether RMI server can be used in this context. Regarding the NTP server, I did not mean to get the time every time a message was sent/received. My point was to get the time from the NTP server and then synchronize the system time with the received time. This synchronization could be carried out once in every 15 - 30 minutes.

Comment: I followed the link you provided and got a working client synched with a UK NTP server. Although in order to synch the system time wouldn't I need admin rights? If its possible without admin rights how can I do it ? Thanks !

Comment: @Giannis, you might need admin privileges to update the system time. If you are unable to update the system time, I would propose the following approach: periodically (say once every 15-30 min) get the time from the NTP server from inside your application. Calculate the difference between the received time and the current system time. This value will be your offset. Whenever you make use of the current system time in your messages, add/subtract this offset value to get the correct time value.

Answer (score 3):

Unless both source and destination is synched to the same time-source, system time can differ by several seconds, or even several hours if source and destination is in different timezones and you use local time.

What you could do is measure the time from you send your packet until you get a reply. This is not 100% safe, as two packets can travel two different routes.

Answer (score 0):

If the receiver is the one asking for the message, then you can record the exact time when the request was made and when the message came back. The difference between them is the result you're looking for.

Comment: Hm in most cases that doesn't happen although sometimes there are requests. Thanks for suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

Joachim is correct.  Unless both machines have clocks that are well synch'ed with a reliable clock, you don't have much chance of measuring the time taken for a point-to-point message.

You are better of measuring round-trip times; i.e. the elapsed time between sending a message and receiving a reply.  You can measure this with a clock that is not synchronized to any external source.

Answer (score 0):

TDOA (Time-Difference of Arrival) is probably your most accurate bet.  It doesn't require time syncing between two hosts and still gives you a pretty accurate RTT.

You essentially measure time 4 different times:

```
x1 = sender send time
y1 = receiver receive time
y2 = receiver send time
x2 - sender receive time
```

so you can calculate the RTT by essentially subtracting out the processing time of receiver (y):

```
x2 - (y2 - y1) - x1
```

For the most precise current time in java use System.nanoTime();